# How to specify setuptools entrypoints in a pyproject.toml

Tags: python, setuptools, program-entry-point, python-packaging, pyproject.toml

I have a setup.py like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name="myproject",
    package_dir={"": "src"},
    packages=find_packages("src"),
    entry_points={
        "console_scripts": [
            "my-script = myproject.myscript:entrypoint",
        ],
    },
)
```

How can I write that `entry_points` configuration in pyproject.toml using setuptools?

I'm guessing something like this, going on [setuptools' pyproject.toml docs](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/pyproject_config.html#dynamic-metadata), which says I need to use "INI format" following [the docs that references for entry-points](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/entry-points/) but it doesn't seem to give an example, and my guess at how to combine the setuptools syntax with the pyproject.toml syntax is wrong (I get a traceback from `pip install -e .` that reports `pip._vendor.tomli.TOMLDecodeError: Invalid value`, pointing at the `entry-points` line in pyproject.toml):

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools", "setuptools-scm"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[metadata]
name = "myproject"

[tool.setuptools]
package-dir = {"" = "src"}

[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["src"]

[tool.setuptools.dynamic]
entry-points =
    my-script = myproject.myscript:entrypoint
```

Note I have a stub setup.py alongside that pyproject.toml, like this (which I read I need to support `pip install -e .` i.e. "editable installation"):

```
from setuptools import setup

if __name__ == "__main__":
    setup()
```

Answer (score 11):

See the [specification](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/pyproject-toml/#entry-points) and this [guide](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/writing-pyproject-toml/#creating-executable-scripts):

```
[project.scripts]
spam-cli = "spam:main_cli"

[project.gui-scripts]
spam-gui = "spam:main_gui"

[project.entry-points."spam.magical"]
tomatoes = "spam:main_tomatoes"
```

Also nowadays (and since the adoption of [*PEP-660*](https://peps.python.org/pep-0660/)), you should not need the (stub) `setup.py` script at all for editable installation. Simply use `python -m pip install --editable .`.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm quite surprised by that spec with all the [project] sections -- is the link in this comment (below) out of date less than a year later?  For example, it says to put the project name in a [metadata] section, not in a [prooject] section https://godatadriven.com/blog/a-practical-guide-to-setuptools-and-pyproject-toml/
Specs are great for implementors but to get a project going quickly an example is a lot faster
Edit: oh, in that blog I now see they're using pyproject.toml AND setup.cfg :-|

Comment: This blog is out of date, yes. It is still correct, you can use `setup.cfg`, without problem, but nowadays if you start a new project it is probably better to go directly for `pyproject.toml` instead.

Comment: Also for *editable* installation, there is no need for `setup.py` anymore.

Comment: Note that in order to use `pyproject.toml` *without* `setup.py`, you need to require a recent-enough version of `setuptools`, like so:



`requires = ["setuptools>=61.2", ...]`


Also note that his doesn't affect your dev environment (unless `--no-build-isolation` is passed to `pip`)

Comment: Link is dead and answer is possibly outdated again? Is this the current spec? https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/entry-points/

Comment: @BradyGilg Thanks for the notification. I updated the answer with newest link to specification and additional link to guide.